# C# sync socket exception on receive method: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, socketexception, gprs

Please see code below, it is not very stable in my windows service, after starting for a while, it throw the error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

The error was catched on : **readsize = listensocket2.Receive(buffer_receive);**

The project is on a data communication center, the clients are GPRS DTU socket client.

Please help!!!

Part I:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(RemsSocket.myip, RemsSocket.webport);
            Socket listensocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listensocket.Bind(endpoint);
            listensocket.Listen(200);
            Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RemsSocket.listen_send));
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start(listensocket);
    }
```

Part II:

```
    public static void listen_send(object source)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            done.Reset();
            Socket listensocket = (Socket)source;
            listensocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptcallback_send), listensocket);
            done.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    public static void acceptcallback_send(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        done.Set();
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket listensocket2 = socket.EndAccept(ar);
        byte[] buffer_validate = new byte[buffersize];
        string hostcode = "";
        byte[] buffer_send = Hex.HexStringToByteArray(validate_code);
        listensocket2.Send(buffer_send, 0, buffer_send.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        listensocket2.Receive(buffer_validate);
        int readsize = buffer_validate.Length; //listensocket2.EndReceive(ar);
        if (readsize > 0)
        {
            bool success = FirstValidate(buffer_validate, ref hostcode);
            bool validate = BLL.ExtHostBLL.CanCommunicate(hostcode); 
            if (success && validate)
            {
                LoopSendReceive(hostcode, listensocket2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Part III:

```
    public static void LoopSendReceive(string hostcode, Socket listensocket2)
    {
        listensocket2.Blocking = true;
        byte[] buffer_receive = new byte[buffersize];
        bool validate = BLL.ExtHostBLL.CanCommunicate(hostcode); 
        while (validate)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            int readsize;
            bool success;
            IPEndPoint clientipe = (IPEndPoint)listensocket2.RemoteEndPoint;
            byte commandByte = Hex.HexStringToByteArray(command_8);
            listensocket2.Send(commandByte, 0, commandByte.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            listensocket2.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
            int countSocketException = 0;
            readsize = listensocket2.Receive(buffer_receive);
            if (readsize != 0)
                {
                    clientipe = (IPEndPoint)listensocket2.RemoteEndPoint;
                    ClientDto client = hostList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Ip == clientipe.Address.ToString());
                    ParseChannel.AlertStatus[] data;
                    ParseChannel channel = new ParseChannel();
                    success = channel.Parse(buffer_receive, client, out data);
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    SaveData(data, client);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error already tells you what went wrong. The client did not respond within the time out period.

Comment: Another possibility is the established connection failed. anyway, the exception has made it broken, could you please provide me a solution to ignore it and keep it working?

Comment: If you really want to ignore it, put a try catch around it, but I doubt that would be a smart thing to do. After all, if you can ignore the connection being lost, then why did you make it in the first place?

Comment: We need some more code since this code should not be the issue.

Comment: And if we ignore the exception, next time RECEIVE maybe receive wrong data which is from previous SEND.

Comment: Bauss, I have post some more code on, the code is on the second communication, the first communication is about validation, if validated, continue to loop the second one. I will try to post most of the code.

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up wire shark and see what is happening on the wire.

Comment: New exception is as below, Pls anybody help?
Application: REMSServerService.exe Framework 
Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: Unknown exception。
Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Stack in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptCallback(System.Object) in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.RegisteredWaitCallback(System.Object, Boolean) 在 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)